# How to change objects' type in a collective way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have different number objects such as a = 1, b = 2. I want to use iterate method to change them into jQuery objects as followings

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
var ArrayToJQuery = [a, b];

for (var obj in ArrayToJQuery) {
    obj = $("<div>").text(obj);
}

a.click(function(){ alert($(this).text())}); //error
```

I have tried for, forin, forEach. None of them works.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: The array just contains the values of the variables, it doesn't contain references to the variables themselves. You can't change the value of variables indirectly like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of thing, it's best to use object properties rather than variables:

```
var stuff = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
var key;
for (key in stuff) {
    stuff[key] = $("<div>").text(stuff[key]);
}
```

Instead of the `for-in` you could use jQuery's `$.each`:

```
var stuff = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
$.each(stuff, function(key, entry) {
    stuff[key] = $("<div>").text(entry);
});
```

Comment: But everytime I refer to my object, I need to call stuff.a
I want to call a directly

Comment: @user1978421: Yes. (You don't "call" properties, you "use" them, but yes.) For what you're doing, you need a container, and so using the container when referring to the thing (`stuff.a`) is a requirement for what you're doing. (Okay, technically you don't **need** a container, you could use `eval`, but it's much, much better to just use the container object.)

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery .each for this.

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) { alert( index + ": " + value );});
```

Please check this link for more detail with example.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/